# java minecraft error unrecognized VM option UseConcMarkSweepGC

Tags: javascript, java, minecraft

So i was trying to make my own Free Server so i watched a tutorial how to do that with Hamachi
so i tried then came this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE5Ak.png)

i already tried to find where i can fix it or sth like that but i dont know yet.

Here is the link to the Tutorial i tried with .
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RpA14YdEe0&t=154s
I´d be very happy if you can help me .

Comment: The minecraft tag is about developing mods, writing code. Not troubleshooting how to run the game.

Comment: dir /s minecraft_launcher.json    (from root)   make a backup and just delete it.  I am assuming you are on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

The CMS collector has been deprecated as of JDK9; you're on JDK16, and it's been entirely removed at this point. It is rather unlikely you want the CMS collector. That tutorial is rather hopelessly out of date if it is advising that you use it.

I suggest you use the Z Garbage Collector instead. It has similar properties (lots of very short collection cycles that don't freeze the entire VM), but is better. `-XX:+UseZGC` is how to turn it on.

It's that or downgrade to e.g. JDK8 which still has the old CMS.

Comment: so wha im supossed to do

Comment: Find a better tutorial, and, replace `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` with `-XX:+UseZGC`; that seemd rather obvious.